# expose unknown JavaScript object methods from third-party code

Tags: javascript, object, properties, firebug, inspect

I am looking for a way to expose the type and methods of an unknown JavaScript object.

I am implementing third-party code that has limited documentation for their methods, so I do not have access to any documentation that would tell me what sort of object I should expect in `response`.

Is there any way to ascertain what type of object this is and expose the methods it contains?

```
for (var i = 0; i <= response.length - 1; i++) {
     console.log(response.i);
}
```

The output in the Firebug Console:

> response: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],....

Comment: console.dir(response) will give an expanded view

Comment: You want `response[i]`, not `response.i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try

```
console.dir(response);
```

It lists all the object's properties, and their respective types are indicated by colorization:

- red key: Constructor functions
- green key: methods
- black key: other

  - red value: string
  - green value: object
  - blue value: boolean
  - gray value: `undefined`/`null`

This list is not exhaustive, and I haven't found any documentation on it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Darhazer I'm sorry, that was supposed to be a rhetorical question. Edit... it's now a suggestion with some more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for in

```
  function printProperties(response, path){
      path = path || "";
     for (var prop in  response) {
         if(typeof response[prop] == 'object'){
             printProperties(response[prop], path + prop  + ".");
             continue;
          }

         console(path  + prop + " = " + response[prop]);
    }
}
```

​
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mVJCw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as a property to `window` and the use the DOM browser in firebug, it allows you to examine the entire object tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see it just by your self:

1. Open Chrome Inspector -> Web Console
2. `console.log(response);`
3. Enjoy, there you can view all properties recursively with details